# getch() reads two characters from one arrow key press

Tags: c++

Today i was testing how key pressing might work in C++ and made simple loop for it,and found that getch() duplicate itself for some reason or idk what is going on honestly,just look at that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define VK_H 0x48
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int n=1;
int total=0;
bool theEnd=true;

while(theEnd)
{
    cout<<total<<endl;
    getch();

    if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT))
    {
        total -=n;
    }else if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT))
    {
        total +=n;
    }else if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) && GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F1))
    {
        total = 0;
    } else if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE))
    {
        break;
    }
}
cout<<total<<endl;
}
```

Its pretty simple.Program starts with a loop,where endlessly outputs value of variable "total",and after pressing left/right buttons "total" decrements/increments by 1.

Its was worked fine and perfect when i was using system("pause"); Sleep(milliseconds); cin.get();*(but this one assume pressing enter each time,so it is not proper one)* ,all that output right value on the screen after each pressing on the buttons.But in case with getch(); it somehow appear to working like only one time per/two cycles of the loop.

So the result i've get is like this: i'm pressing button right - current loop working fine,but next one working like without getch(),incrementing and outputting one more time without my command...

I've siting and thinking couple hours,trying find any answers in google and here but nothing...

P.S.without using getch() or other things for purpose stoping loop till next pressing - it will add not +1 to total by single pressing(as i need),but hundreds(average pressing key will do 150-300 loops lol).

Comment: Don't worry about that, `getch()` is not supposed to be used in any serious program, and it's not even a standard function. So don't worry too much about it.

Comment: does [this much simpler program](https://pastebin.com/e4VZtj0E) still demonstrate your problem?

Comment: @Iharob Al Asimi what serious programmers use instead then?))

Comment: @Ryan Haining no its not,problem was rather in arrow keys.

Comment: @Engelard Perhaps something that is not from a toy library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [MS documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/078sfkak.aspx)

> **Remarks**
>
> The _getch and_getwch functions read a single character from the
> console without echoing the character. None of these functions can be
> used to read CTRL+C. When reading a function key or an arrow key, each
> function must be called twice; the first call returns 0 or 0xE0, and
> the second call returns the actual key code.

When you press arrow keys, the input is 2 chars

Comment: 1.tried _getch - completely same thing,same result._getwch dont working at all(but libraries included).


2.i changed arrow key to just 'H' button and it stop working(current 'if' statement),at least it dont working with getch,if i'm delete getch from code - 'H' works fine...

Comment: @Engelard Did you add [extra call](https://pastebin.com/LkWef26T) to `getch()` to read that extra char?

Comment: Omg it worked out! I used simple getch(not _getch) and now it work as it should.Problem resolved,all hail Killzone Kid!